# Valgrind relative paths in suppression file

Tags: c++, valgrind, suppress-warnings, suppression

Valgrind can generate suppression file, but it contains absolute paths to libraries by default. But I want to share this suppression file between multiple computers, my project may be stored on different paths.

How can I specify relative paths to libraries in .supp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) says:

> Locations may be names of either shared objects, functions, or source lines. They begin with obj:, fun:, or src: respectively. Function, object, and file names to match against may use the wildcard characters * and ?. Source lines are specified using the form filename[:lineNumber].

Therefore, you can use wildcards and specify relative paths.

For an inspiration see the default suppression file shipped with valgrind (on my computer it is at `/usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp`), or various `*.supp` files on the [git mirror](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=tree;h=3dc7675318dc8f7f2fdd7340b8cb839964ee6f4b;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Thank you! I just replaced path to libraries with * symbol and now it works well